# Empty report when binding a DevExpress XtraReport to an IList

Tags: .net, devexpress, xtrareport

Because the XtraReport designer isn't into object data sources, I first used a DB table to mimic the data structure of my report data, and the report works nicely like that. However, when I try and assign a data source in code, like below, I get an empty report. What could I be doing wrong?

```
_report.DataSource =
    ProductionDataHelper.GetReportData(deptId, deptDateFilter.SelectedStartDate ?? DateTime.Now).OrderBy(
        r => r.DeptDisplayIndex ?? int.MaxValue).ThenBy(r => r.KpiDisplayIndex ?? int.MaxValue).ThenBy(r => r.Category);
KpiReportViewer.Report = _report;
```

I have set the design time `DataSource` property to null, and I know that `GetReportData` works because the previous report component, from Telerik, displays a four page report. Report date returns the result of `ToList` on an EF query.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that it is not possible to use collections based on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface in XtraReport.The [XtraReport.DataSource](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_DataSourcetopic) support collection implements the `IList, IBindingList` or `ITypedList` interfaces.
Anyway, you shouldn't wait for a solution here instead of [reporting this issue in DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=bugreport). If the problem exists, it will be resolved or you will be provided with a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I will report the issue there as well, but I did say in my post I was passing the result of a `ToList<T>` call to the report; this result being of type List<T>, which does implement `IList`.